# OAuth resource owner password flow and HMAC

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, hmac

I have a web api application which implements the Resource Owner Password flow from OAuth specification. Everything works correctly.

Actually I configure everything in my WebApiConfig class by using an Authentication filter like this

```
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add( new HostAuthenticationFilter( OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType ) );
```

As some of my customer asked for a different method of authentication I am evaluating to add a couple of features to my services but stil did not have clear how those features can work together.

In particular I cam across a [link](http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/) which explain in very easy words how to implement a HMAC authentication in web api.

Can I implement this authentication method and let the client to choose which one he want to use? Do they can cohesist together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your web api service can send back multiple schemes in the `WWW-Authenticate` challenge. In your case it can send back '**bearer**' and '**hmac**' for example.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10239970/18044) for more info on using multiple schemes.

BTW, it's not your web api service that supports Resource Owner Password flow. The client uses this flow to get a token from the authorization server that it can use in a bearer scheme with your service (resource server). HTH.